# How to add text box runtime and insert its value to db in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to create Curd app using AngularJS & MVC.

In that I am able to add, update and delete particular data from grid, but there is one task where I am getting stuck.

Here what I need to do is, I should be able to add multiple run time text box on that insert page to take any no of input from user, so I don't know how to do it and how to add those run time added text box values in DB.

It would be much appreciated if you help me on this.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  How are you deciding how many input boxes to display? Or is your user deciding how many, through some selector or by pressing a button over and over?  And what does your server accept, just an array of strings?

Comment: In general, Angular is a *data* framework, it's not a UI framework.  If you can express what kind of data you want to handle, the UI will take care of itself.  Here, though, you seem to be asking about designing a UI for some completely unknown data, which is very strange.

Comment: See what i want is, there will be a button on page, "add new item", which should add a text box in page each time when it gets clicked. And suppose i have clicked on it 5 times, then in ui i should get 5 text boxes and when submit that page, all these 5 text box data should be sent to server for db entry.

Comment: that's a bit clearer, but still not descriptive enough.  What are these items you are asking your users to add?  You aren't asking the user to just hit the "add item" button as many times as they like, and type a random word in each box;  you obviously are trying to gather some specific information, but it's difficult to know the right way to help you gather that info when we are in the dark about what it is.

Comment: Let me give you example, Let say there is a screen called "Project Details", in which thee are fix fields, Project name, Project Description, Total hours. now as project is any kind of project like construction project or like law firm project or let say a project of any marriage event. So here i want that user can add any other property what he requires. So it would be like when user click on "Add New Property" button, he will get 2 text box in same line, one is for label and another is for description on that label. and property can be 2 or 4 or upto nth number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/9072/)

```
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,val) in data">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" ng-model="val.text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTextbox()">
          Add Textbox
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="sendDataToServer()">
          Send Data
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Result = {{data}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller's code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.addTextbox = function(){
      $scope.data.push({'text':''});
    }

    $scope.sendDataToServer = function(){
       console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.data));
       $http({
          url: 'your_server_url',
          method: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify($scope.data),
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': undefined
          }
      }).then(function(res) {
          // do stuff on success
      }, function(errorMsg) {
          console.log(errorMsg);
          // showing error
      });
    }
}
```

Here you will get all textbox's data into `$scope.data`, Now you can send this data by clicking `Send Data` button.

Provide the `url` where you want to submit this data.

Comment if you have any issue.

Comment: Awesome, This one is working as i want, thank you, can you please guide me for two text box at a time, i mean what i am trying to develop is like "Label" : "Description", here i want user to add label and description both in two text box, what should i do to add another text box??

Comment: OMG! you did it for me, thanks, thanks a lot Devidas. it is what i am looking for. thank you.